# Different between object.propertyName and object["propertyName"] in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've been learning Js recently from "[JavaScript the Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742)", and according to my understanding

`Object.propertyName` yields same result as `Object["propertyName"]`(Please correct me if I'm not right and describe the difference of the two).

I'm trying to augment the Function.prototype to make a *method* available to all functions as below:

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
            this.prototype[name]= func;
    };
```

And it's working fine.However, when I'm replacing the `this.prototype[name]` with `this.prototype.name`, it'll fail functioning as expected!

This is how I'm testing it:

```
 Number.method("myRoundFunction", function () {
        return Math[this < 0 ? "ceil" : "floor"](this);
    });
    console.log((-10 / 3).myRoundFunction());
```

This shows the expected value (-3) when using `this.prototype[name]`, but

> (-3.3333333333333335).myRoundFunction is not a function

on changing it to `this.prototype.name`

Could someone possibly clarify why this is happening?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's happening is that `name` is a variable, and cannot be used directly with dot notation.  To better illustrate the issue, let's say you pass a value of `"newMethod"` for name.  Now when you do:

```
this.prototype[name] = func;
```

...it is equivalent to writing:

```
this.prototype["newMethod"] = func;
```

But when you do:

```
this.prototype.name = func;
```

...you are assigning to the `name` property of the object, and not to the `newMethod` property.  The variable that you passed under the parameter `name` is not referenced at all in the above statement.

The syntax that would preform the assignment you expect is:

```
this.prototype.newMethod = func;
```

But you cannot express that using dot notation and the `name` variable (except perhaps by cheating and using string concatenation and `eval()`).  In such a case you have to use the array-subscript notation instead.

Answer (score 3):

Prototype defines the JS classes definition; whereas something like Number.parse is a direct function on a type (similar to a static method).  If I do:

```
myclass.prototype["name"] = function() { }
```

I'm adding a method to the next instance of the class, whereas:

```
myclass["name"] = function() { }
```

Adds the function directly to the class object, not to the next instance of myclass.  I think this is what's happening when I see the definition of `Number.method`?

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

`name` is a variable, when you use `this.prototype.name`, it is the same as you call `this.prototype["name"]`, not what you think as `this.prototype[name]`.